# Sending a dm to a user who joins and myself

Tags: python, discord.py

I just want when someone joins the server for the bot to message them AND me including the member's name.

Have not got any error or output.

Sorry if I didn't search deep enough for answers but the ones I saw were pretty old

````
from discord.ext import commands
from math import floor
import math
from keep_alive import keep_alive

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  await member.send("message here including name of person who joined".format(member.name))
  user = "my id"
  await user.send("message to me including name of person who just joined".format(member.name))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have member intents enabled for your bot.

Comment: I do - I have both presence and server members enabled

Comment: Oh nvm after doing further research it turns out you need to define it in the code.  The only thing that does not work now is the message that is meant to be sent to me

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching your user id with `user = bot.fetch_user(your_id)`

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_user